# Get Specefic Value From loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this

```
$sel_sub = $conn->query("SELECT p.id AS pID , p.pack_id, p.tender_id, p.item_name,s.total_volume AS tv FROM pack_items p LEFT JOIN suppling_details s ON s.pack_item = p.id WHERE p.tender_id = $tender ");
```

The result of this query, for example, is 11 results.

Then I will define a variable with a value matching with one of the query results.

I need the system to search inside the query result about the variable value and print its sort number  .

```
$i = 0;
while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_sub)) {
    $i++;
    $pdf->Cell(200, 15, $i . $rec['item_name'].$user['item_name'], 1, 1, 'C', 1);

}
```

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. Why not update the query's `where` clause to give you back the row you require?

Comment: That will return Just one result,
For example
Give me the students name inside Class b 
The count was 11
Will ,
Now every student has a card 
For example i have s student called Joun
i need to search about John inside the loop and get his sort Number

Comment: What is the question? Is something not working?

Comment: I don't see that magical "sort number" anywhere in your code/question.